# getLocationOnScreen returns 0 inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use a recyclerview that has 20 row count. Each row has unique row type.

```
getItemViewType (int index) {
    return index;
}
```

I want to get the location of 10th item when scrolling. I use `setOnScrollListener` method to listen scroll. Below code works inside `onScrolled` callback.

```
if(womanDetailViewHolder == null)
    return;
womanDetailViewHolder.rowLayout. getLocationOnScreen(out);
Log.i("LOG1", " X: " + out[0] + " Y: " + out[1]);
```

womanDetailViewHolder is created but not showed, y comes 0. But I expect a value that bigger than the height of screen. y comes as expected when womanDetailViewHolder is visible on screen. Then I scroll to 18th-20th row, y comes 0 again. I expect a value that smaller than -1*screenHeight.

Am I wrong? Or how can I fix these values?

Answer (score 2):

`RecyclerView` has only views visible on the screen. All offscreen `ViewHolder`s are detached and stored in `RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool` until they're visible again. In the meantime they are not laid out at all.

Returning position as `itemViewType` violates entire `ViewHolder` pattern and should never be used.

You'll need to manually count distance using your items height (assuming they have the same size) and position of currently visible item or RecyclerView scroll value.